# How to get an email address with a LinkedIn signup API with PHP

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I got this code from some tutorial about linked signup, but the tutorial provide just the basic information. I need to get the user email also... How can I do that?

Here is the code:

#### auth.php

This is the link where I get access form on likedin.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $config['base_url']             =   '';
    $config['callback_url']         =   '';
    $config['linkedin_access']      =   '';
    $config['linkedin_secret']      =   '';

    include_once "linkedin.php";

    # First step is to initialize with your consumer key and secret. We'll use an out-of-band oauth_callback
    $linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );
    //$linkedin->debug = true;

    # Now we retrieve a request token. It will be set as $linkedin->request_token
    $linkedin->getRequestToken();
    $_SESSION['requestToken'] = serialize($linkedin->request_token);

    # With a request token in hand, we can generate an authorization URL, which we'll direct the user to
    //echo "Authorization URL: " . $linkedin->generateAuthorizeUrl() . "\n\n";
    header("Location: " . $linkedin->generateAuthorizeUrl()); ?>
```

#### demo.php

This is the script that I get after signup.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $config['base_url']             =   'http://xxx/linkedin/auth.php';
    $config['callback_url']         =   'http://xxx/linkedin/demo.php';
    $config['linkedin_access']      =   '';
    $config['linkedin_secret']      =   '';

    include_once "linkedin.php";

    # First step is to initialize with your consumer key and secret. We'll use an out-of-band oauth_callback
    $linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );
    //$linkedin->debug = true; if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'])){
    $_SESSION['oauth_verifier']     = $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];

    $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
    $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
    $linkedin->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

    $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = serialize($linkedin->access_token);
    header("Location: " . $config['callback_url']);
    exit;}   else{
    $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
    $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
    $linkedin->access_token     =   unserialize($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);}

    # You now have a $linkedin->access_token and can make calls on behalf of the current member
    $xml_response = $linkedin->getProfile("~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url)");


    $id = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(id)');
    $fname = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(first-name)');
    $lname = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(last-name)');
    $headline = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(headline)');
    $picture = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(picture-url)');

    $id = trim(strip_tags($id));
    $fname = trim(strip_tags($fname));
    $lname = trim(strip_tags($lname));
    $headline = trim(strip_tags($headline));
    $picture = trim(strip_tags($picture)); ?>
```

#### linkedin.php

This is LinkedIn library:

```
<?php require_once("OAuth.php"); class LinkedIn {
    public $base_url = "http://api.linkedin.com";
    public $secure_base_url = "https://api.linkedin.com";
    public $oauth_callback = "oob";
    public $consumer;
    public $request_token;
    public $access_token;
    public $oauth_verifier;
    public $signature_method;
    public $request_token_path;
    public $access_token_path;
    public $authorize_path;

    function __construct($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_callback = NULL)
    {

        if($oauth_callback) {
            $this->oauth_callback = $oauth_callback;
        }

        $this->consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $this->oauth_callback);
        $this->signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
        $this->request_token_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/requestToken";
        $this->access_token_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/accessToken";
        $this->authorize_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/authorize";
    }

    function getRequestToken()
    {
        $consumer = $this->consumer;
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL, "GET", $this->request_token_path);
        $request->set_parameter("oauth_callback", $this->oauth_callback);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $consumer, NULL);
        $headers = Array();
        $url = $request->to_url();
        $response = $this->httpRequest($url, $headers, "GET");
        parse_str($response, $response_params);
        $this->request_token = new OAuthConsumer($response_params['oauth_token'], $response_params['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
    }

    function generateAuthorizeUrl()
    {
        $consumer = $this->consumer;
        $request_token = $this->request_token;
        return $this->authorize_path . "?oauth_token=" . $request_token->key;
    }

    function getAccessToken($oauth_verifier)
    {
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->request_token, "GET", $this->access_token_path);
        $request->set_parameter("oauth_verifier", $oauth_verifier);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->request_token);
        $headers = Array();
        $url = $request->to_url();
        $response = $this->httpRequest($url, $headers, "GET");
        parse_str($response, $response_params);
        $this->access_token = new OAuthConsumer($response_params['oauth_token'], $response_params['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
    }

    function getProfile($resource = "~")
    {
        $profile_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/" . $resource;
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "GET", $profile_url);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
        $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com"); # this is the realm
        # This PHP library doesn't generate the header correctly when a realm is not specified.
        # Make sure there is a space and not a comma after OAuth
        // $auth_header = preg_replace("/Authorization\: OAuth\,/", "Authorization: OAuth ", $auth_header);
        // # Make sure there is a space between OAuth attribute
        // $auth_header = preg_replace('/\"\,/', '", ', $auth_header);

        // $response will now hold the XML document
        $response = $this->httpRequest($profile_url, $auth_header, "GET");
        return $response;
    }

    function setStatus($status)
    {
        $profile_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/~";
        $status_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/~/current-status";
        echo "Setting status...\n";
        $xml = "<current-status>" . htmlspecialchars($status, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8") . "</current-status>";
        echo $xml . "\n";
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "PUT", $status_url);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
        $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");

        $response = $this->httpRequest($profile_url, $auth_header, "GET");
        return $response;
    }

    # Parameters should be a query string starting with "?"
    # Example search("?count=10&start=10&company=LinkedIn");
    function search($parameters)
    {
        $search_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,site-standard-profile-request,headline),num-results)" . $parameters;
        //$search_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people-search?keywords=facebook";

        echo "Performing search for: " . $parameters . "<br />";
        echo "Search URL: $search_url <br />";
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "GET", $search_url);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
        $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");
        $response = $this->httpRequest($search_url, $auth_header, "GET");
        return $response;
    }

    function httpRequest($url, $auth_header, $method, $body = NULL)
    {
        if (!$method) {
            $method = "GET";
        };

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header)); // Set the headers.

        if ($body) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header, "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8"));
        }

        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $data;
    }}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The email address is only available to the authenticated user and not his/her connections.

1. Make sure you've requested the **r_emailaddress** member permissions from the user when authorizing your application. *[Authentication](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)* covers authentication and grant member permissions in detail.
2. Make the following GET call to fetch the email address for the authenticated user:

   ```
   GET http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address)
   ```

Comment: Thanks. This was added relatively recently (Aug 6, 2012)

Answer (score 19):

For people searching for v2 urls

please follow the below urls

```
 payload = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': token,
        'redirect_uri': s.SOCIAL_AUTH_CALLBACK_URL,
        'client_id': s.LINKED_IN_CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': s.LINKED_IN_CLIENT_SECRET
    }

POST "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken"
```

to get access token

```
GET "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me"
```

to get the user data send auth token in header

```
GET "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))"
```

to get user email address.

Comment: can i get email and other information like name and phone together @pawan

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/primary-contact-api

Answer (score 7):

You can get email address via api 
$this->userProfileUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,public-profile-url,email-address)?oauth2_access_token=";

But you have to set scope like $oauth->scope = 'r_basicprofile,r_emailaddress';
use Oauth
https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api

Or try
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Answer (score 5):

You can access the linkedin user email address with below EP:

```
`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))`
```

Make sure that you have defined the scope 'r_emailaddress' in your library.
You can use below curl request to fetch the data:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Authorization: Bearer '. $token,
      'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0',
      'Accept: application/json',
      'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $body = substr($response, $headerSize);
    $response_body = json_decode($body,true);
```

$response_body will return the following response:

```
Array (
    [elements] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [handle] => urn:li:emailAddress:123456
                    [handle~] => Array
                        (
                            [emailAddress] => your@email.in
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Your comment has helped me a lot, however, I cannot access "emailAddress" because I have a problem with this sign (handle ~)
What would be the correct way to access the email to save it in the database? ... Thank you,

Comment: $a = 'handle~';
$email = $response_body->elements[0]->$a->emailAddress;

Answer (score 3):

You should pass '&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress' this at time of AccessToken Request

Step 1: AccessToken Request will be like

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code={Your code}&redirect_uri={Yourredirect_uri}&client_id={Your client_id}&client_secret={Your client_secret }&scope=r_liteprofile+r_emailaddress
```

This will return you the AccessToken using which You do have to make 2 more requests 1 is for Email and Profile Details

Step 2: for Email request will be like

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))&oauth2_access_token={AccessToken You get from step 1}'
```

Step 3: for basic profile request will be like

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,emailAddress,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token={AccessToken You get from step 1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The LinkedIn API does not offer the email address as part of the profile object. See the docs [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api) to read what data is available.

EDIT:
See Kamyar's answer. Apparently as of August 2012 LinkedIn now allows pulling the email addresses.

Comment: There is some option, but I am not that level experienced :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
->elements[0]->{"handle~"}->emailAddress
```

goodluck

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:** AccessToken Request

```
$postData = array(
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'code' => urldecode(trim($_GET['code'])),
    'redirect_uri' => url_for('social_login/linkedin'),
    'client_id' => CFG_LINKEDIN_APP_ID,
    'client_secret' => CFG_LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY
);

$ch = curl_init("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken");    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);    
$body = substr($response, $header_size);

curl_close($ch);

if(!$response)
{
    die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));       
}
                
$response = json_decode($body,true);
```

In **$response** you will find the AccessToken using which You do have to make 2 more requests 1 is for Email and Profile Details

**Step 2:** profile request

```
$access_token = $response['access_token']; 
   
$ch = curl_init('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,emailAddress,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token=' . $access_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);        
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Step 3:** for Email request

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))&oauth2_access_token=' . $access_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);        
$response2 = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Result:** user data

```
$user = [
    'first_name' => current($response['firstName']['localized']),
    'last_name' => current($response['lastName']['localized']),
    'photo' => $response['profilePicture']['displayImage~']['elements'][0]['identifiers'][0]['identifier'],
    'email' => $response2['elements'][0]['handle~']['emailAddress']
];
```